# How to View Custom Event Parameter Values in GA4 Exploration Reports?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm sending an event with parameters to Google Analytics using the following code:

```
gtag('event', 'et_change_material_', {
    'name': value
});
```

I can see the parameter values in the real-time report. How can I reflect and view these values in the exploration section to generate a report for this event?